# How to Remove a Comma & Space (, ) behind a word (hello) in PHP

Tags: php

Hi this is my string (aa, bb, cc, dd, ee) gathered from a database field.
Let's say I'm done with 'bb', so i would like to remove, maybe ", bb". 
How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks,
Om

Comment: Is there a reason that str_replace won't work?

Comment: Have you made any attempts with code? We usually like to see that as we want to help you fix an issue not give you a solution.

Comment: *Achha Hain..* Please Share Your Tried Code OM.

Comment: Or may be [`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for that, i.e.:

```
$string = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee";
echo str_replace(", bb", "", $string);
//aa, cc, dd, ee
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:

```
$my_string = str_replace('bb', '', $my_string);
$my_string = str_replace(',,', ',', $my_string);
```

The “right” way:

- Explode your string to an array
- Remove the element equals to “bb”
- Implode the array to get back a string

Code:

```
$student_id_field = 'aa,bb,cc,dd,ee';
$student_arr = explode(',', $student_id_field);
$student_arr = array_filter($student_arr, function ($element) { return $element != $student_id; })
$student_id_field = implode(',', $student_arr);
```

Comment: Hi, Thang, I did this but you see, "bb" is a variable, and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: my code looked like this: $sql="SELECT * FROM assign_incident WHERE teacher_id = $teacher_id";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $student_id_feild = $row['current_student'];
  str_replace(', ' .$student_id.'', '', $student_id_feild);

Comment: Is it true that  $student_id_field == 'aa, bb, cc, dd, ee' ?  And $student_id == 'bb' ?

Comment: Yes, $student_id_field = 'aa, bb, cc, dd, ee'

Answer (score 1):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) would do the job

```
$mystring = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee";
$toBeRemoved = "bb";
echo str_replace(", " . $toBeRemoved, "", str_replace($toBeRemoved . ",", "", $mystring));
```

Note: `str_replace` used twice to get match, whether it's occurring first, last or in middle.

Answer (score 0):

Php's `str_replace` function provides the ability to change the string as you wish.

```
str_replace(search query, replacement value, search area)
str_replace(", ", "", array(aa, ee, bb, cc));
```

There are multiple other ways to skin the cat as well. If you are getting these values from a database, you could extract them as an array and iterate over them. You could also explode the values on the "," and turn them into an array,